# How can we UnPivot items in a Data Frame, Transpose Rows to Columns, and a Parse String to get Dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pivot

I have a data frame that looks like this..

```
RCFD0071                                RCFD0081                                 RCFD0426                                 RCFD1350                             RCFD1754                        RCFD1773                           RCFD2130                                 RCFD2143                               RCFD2145                                   file
INT-BEARING BALS DUE FRM DEP INSTS      NONINTEREST-BEARING BALS&CURR&COIN       OTHER IDENTIFIABLE INTANGIBLE ASSETS     FED. FUNDS SOLD & SECURITIES RS.     HELD-TO-MATURITY SECURITIES     AVAILABLE-FOR-SALE SECURITIES      INVEST. IN UNCONSOLIDATED SUBS & CO.     Invest in Unconsolidated Subsid        PREMISES&FIXED ASSETS(INCL CAP LSES)       FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RC0 03312001.txt
1457                                    975697                                   112745                                   161346                               15358                           3510649                            6987                                     0                                      450706                                     FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RC0 03312001.txt
25560                                   292236                                   123288                                   585000                               0                               3080606                            0                                        0                                      105521                                     FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RC0 06302001.txt
17983011                                897105                                   29763                                    15060119                             1347143                         15373763                           22733                                    0                                      570144                                     FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RC0 06302001.txt
1016                                    706018                                   0                                        1166892                              0                               1185021                            0                                        0                                      253232                                     FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RC0 09312001.txt
```

I am trying to figure out how to do the following with UnPivot.

1. transpose the second row to the first column
2. transpose the first row to the second column
3. parse the quater-end dates and use as headers
4. sum all line items, per date, and aggregate by date

Here is what I want to end up with when everything is done.

[image]

I have over 80 fields with data; I can't do this manually.

I know how to do a normal UnPivot, but I don't know how to transpose the second row and move it to the first column, transpose the first row and move it to the second column. Also, I don't know  how to arse the file names, and use them as headers. Is this possible with Python? There are many more columns and many more rows in the data frame, so it's not realistic to do this manually.

Answer (score 2):

Here is step 1 and 2

```
r1 = df.loc[0].copy()
df.loc[0] = df.columns
df.columns = r1

df = df.T
```

Is step 3 suppose to be a renaming?
What dates are you talking about for step 4?
Either way I think steps 3 and 4 should be a separate question so you can add more details.

Comment: I think I see what you're doing here, but when I run this code I get the following error:  ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 101 elements, new values have 73 elements

I need to do a little more research on this.  Thanks.